# Flushing stdout messages of c/c++ based executable

Tags: c, linux, gcc, output-buffering

My question is general and doesn't relate to a specific debugging scenario.

When a program terminate unexpectedly (panic, memory corruption, access violation etc... ) , sometimes the recent stdout messages doesn't appear on the screen, even though they occurred prior to the termination.

That's because stdout messages are first being written to buffer that is also erased upon termination without being written to stdout in advance.

My question is whether there's a generic option to flush all debug messages 
in c/c++ code before program terminate unexpectedly ? (I would prefer using some generic compiler configuration rather that an ad-hoc solution for a specific implementation such as std::cout - if there's such option, I'd be happy to know if it's common to GCC and G++)

Note : I assume that when flushing this buffer for each new arriving message, will damage performance. however, it's only meant for debug version.

thanks

Comment: You should find out where it crashes with a debugger.

Comment: Try `fflush(stdout);`. However, you may want to debug with a debugger instead of printing variable values.

Comment: a generic suggestion, if in C, try to add a `\n` at the end of the format string in printf

Comment: This is what `stderr` is for.

Comment: `setvbuf()` allows you to set the `mode` to unbuffered.

Comment: If, despite the previous suggestions, you really want to disable buffering you can do so with [`setvbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf)

Comment: Realise changing the buffer won't "avoid performance degradation", it could only make performance worse, although with human readable output you won't see a difference, realistically.

Comment: Is this C or C++?  they are not the same thing.

Comment: I assumed there's no difference between c and c++... I'd be happy to know how to flush this buffer on both cases. some documentation references would also be appreciated.

Comment: Please add a snippet of your code to make clear exactly what you're doing.

Comment: If you are using cout, use std::ostream::flush to flush the buffer. An small example would help.

Comment: If `stdout` is to a terminal (as opposed to a pipe or file), it should be line-buffered by default. If you want to force line-buffered output, there are "fake TTY" wrapper programs out there, e.g. `socat` can do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setvbuf to set no buffer

```
setvbuf(stream, NULL, _IONBF, 0)
```